# How to combine column values with delimiters as well as exceptions to delimiters?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "orange", "peach", "")
color <- c("red", "orange", "", "purple")
taste <- c("sweet", "", "sweet", "neutral")

df <- data.frame(fruit, color, taste)
```

I want to add all the columns together into one column named "combined":

```
combined <- c("apple + red + sweet", "orange + orange", "peach + sweet", "purple + neutral")
```

And as a result, I have the following data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(fruit, color, taste, combined)
```

I took a stab at using regex:

```
df %>%
      unite("combined",
            fruit,
            color,
            taste,  
            sep=" + ",
            remove = FALSE)
```

I've been trying to remove "+" when it is in the beginning or in the end or if there's a blank preceding it using the following regex, but it feels sloppy and doesn't seem to achieve exactly what I want:

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(across(any_of(combined), gsub, pattern = "^\\+|\\+  \\+  \\+  \\+|\\+  \\+  \\+|\\+  \\+|\\+$", replacement = "")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We may replace the blanks (`""`) with `NA` and then use `na.rm = TRUE` in `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(.x,  ""))) %>%
  unite(combined, everything(), sep = " + ", na.rm = TRUE, 
     remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
            combined  fruit  color   taste
1 apple + red + sweet  apple    red   sweet
2     orange + orange orange orange    <NA>
3       peach + sweet  peach   <NA>   sweet
4    purple + neutral   <NA> purple neutral
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do `mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(.x,  "")))` but on specific variables (and not everything)?

Comment: @hy9fesh in that case, change the `everything()` to perhaps, `mutate(c(fruit, color), ~ na_if(.x, "")))`

Comment: I tried `mutate_at()` but it combined values from the entire data frame.

Comment: @hy9fesh Sorry, I meant `mutate(across(c(fruit, color), ~...` I missed the `across` by typo

Comment: @hy9fesh full code `df %>%
  mutate(across(c(fruit, color), ~ na_if(.x,  ""))) %>%
  unite(combined, c(fruit, color), sep = " + ", na.rm = TRUE, 
     remove = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

Create a function which takes two strings and produces their sum and apply it using `Reduce` .

```
library(dplyr)

Paste <- function(x, y) paste0(x, ifelse(x == "" | y == "", "", " + "), y)
df %>% mutate(combined = Reduce(Paste, .))
```

giving

```
   fruit  color   taste            combined
1  apple    red   sweet apple + red + sweet
2 orange orange             orange + orange
3  peach          sweet       peach + sweet
4        purple neutral    purple + neutral
```

Comment: Instead of `Paste, .`, is it possible to replace the `.` with specific variables?

Comment: You can replace . with `select(., fruit:color)`, say.

Comment: What if I only want fruit and taste?

Comment: Read about `select`.  Also if you only had two columns then you don't need `Reduce`.  `Paste(fruit, taste)` is enough.